# Need to Understand this code that im using for charts

Tags: c#

```
bool metinoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_metin.Text, out metinoy);
bool oktayoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_oktay.Text, out oktayoy);
bool fatihoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_fatih.Text, out fatihoy);
bool terimoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_terim.Text, out terimoy);
```

What is this lines doing? Result is written to bool variables but not used(I think). If it is used can you explain how.

```
// Full Code
double metinoy, oktayoy, fatihoy, terimoy;
bool metinoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_metin.Text, out metinoy);
bool oktayoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_oktay.Text, out oktayoy);
bool fatihoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_fatih.Text, out fatihoy);
bool terimoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_terim.Text, out terimoy);
// her atama öncesi grafik temizleme
foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
{
  series.Points.Clear();
}
chart1.Series["Notlar"].Points.Add(metinoy);
chart1.Series["Notlar"].Points.Add(oktayoy);
chart1.Series["Notlar"].Points.Add(fatihoy);
chart1.Series["Notlar"].Points.Add(terimoy);

chart1.Series["Notlar"].Points[0].AxisLabel = lbl_metin.Text;
chart1.Series["Notlar"].Points[1].AxisLabel = lbl_oktay.Text;
chart1.Series["Notlar"].Points[2].AxisLabel = lbl_fatih.Text;
chart1.Series["Notlar"].Points[3].AxisLabel = lbl_terim.Text;
chart1.Series["Notlar"].Color = Color.Yellow;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 70;
chart1.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
```

Comment: `bool` results are not used here - they might as well have called just `Parse`. Bools would go to `false` if the parse failed, but obviously you'll need to test for that for this to make any sense.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError If `Parse` was used, the code might error rather than just default to 0.  Perhaps defaulting to 0 is the desired behaviour if it can't be parsed.  But yes, no point having the variable.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: *"they might as well have called just Parse"* - If parse failures should fail loudly with an exception.  It may be perfectly valid business logic to ignore parse failures and proceed with a zero.

Comment: why don't you search `double.tryparse` c#, you will easily find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__

Anyhow `out metinoy`  stores your result which is used later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bool` variables (such as `metinoysonuc`) indeed are not being used.  So you can "safely" remove them ("safe" meaning that the code will still compile and execute):

```
Double.TryParse(txt_metin.Text, out metinoy);
Double.TryParse(txt_oktay.Text, out oktayoy);
Double.TryParse(txt_fatih.Text, out fatihoy);
Double.TryParse(txt_terim.Text, out terimoy);
```

These same operations still produce the parsed results in variables like `metinoy`.

**However**, the real question is... Do you *want* to do anything with those `bool` results?  Those values indicate whether the parsing operation succeeded or failed.  If the parsing operation fails, do you want the code to silently proceed with a value of `0` or do you want to respond to the error?

For example:

```
bool metinoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_metin.Text, out metinoy);
bool oktayoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_oktay.Text, out oktayoy);
bool fatihoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_fatih.Text, out fatihoy);
bool terimoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_terim.Text, out terimoy);

if (!metinoysonuc || !oktayoysonuc || !fatihoysonuc || !terimoysonuc)
{
    // At least one parse operation failed.  Notify the user?
}
```

How you want to handle parse failures is up to you.  The `bool` values simply indicate whether or not the parse operation was successful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer that is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the line `metinoysonuc = Double.TryParse(txt_metin.Text, out metinoy);`

If the string in `txt_metin.Text` is not a valid `double`, then `Double.TryParse` will return `false`, which will also set `metinoysonuc` to `false` and `metinoy` will be [zero](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

If the string in `txt_metin.Text` is a valid `double`, then `Double.TryParse` will return `true`, which will also set `metinoysonuc` to `true` and `metinoy` will contain the parsed `double` that was contained in `txt_metin.Text`.

Although doesn't look like the boolean values are used in your code snippet, it should probably do something if `metinoysonuc` is `false` in this case as `metinoy` will be [zero](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: _"`metinoy` will remain untouched."_ - it will be changed to 0.  A method with `out` vars _must_ assign to them.  In this case it already was zero, since it was only just declared, but it's a point to be aware of elsewhere where it might be the case that it already has a non-zero value.

Comment: It won't be undefined either.  It will be exactly zero.  [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8): _"or zero if the conversion failed"_